# Problem with accessing the array element in java script

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have the array structure like  this

```
"fabricArray": [
            {
                "fabricName": "naveen",
                "color": "blue",
                "dia": "no",
                "rolls": "yes",
                "totalKgs": 545454545,
                "remarks": "good"
            }
        ],
```

I need to get particular feilds like fabricName,etc.how to access it?I have tried every possible method,
like `fabricArray[0].fabricName`
(All the elements present in the array are under same objectId 0) [for more reference see the image from my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Bbc.png).Please help me in this issue

Comment: `objectName.arrayName[index you want to access]`

Comment: Hi @neveen, `fabricArray[0].fabricName` is not working ? can you put the code where you have this object please

Comment: I just made some mistake in my code,i solved it,now its working fine.